# Group differences barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, pivot, geom-bar

I'm still pretty new to R, I'm sorry if the question is a stupid one!

For some descriptives I created a barplot to visualize group differences in my sample. I have two groups of people - suicide attempters and non-attempters. They differ regarding their diagnoses and so far I have a plot showing me how many people per group I have with a certain diagnosis, but I'd like to have a bar representing those people per group who do not have this diagnosis.
So I'd have a bar representing the number of people with MDD in the attempters group, a bar for those without in the attempters group, a bar for those with MDD in the non-attempters and a bar for those without MDD in the non-attempters.

Regarding my data: Everything is coded as 0 or 1, except for the attempters or not.

My old data frame looks something like this:

| code | MDD | Anxiety | PTBS | attempters |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 02 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 03 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 04 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

At first I changed my data from wide to long and recoded the grouping variable attempters to a factor:

```
# create data frame for attempters
data_attempters <- data_gesamt %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(MDD, Anxiety, PTBS),
    names_to = "predictors", values_to = "value") %>%
    filter(value == 1) %>%
  # convert "attempters" to factor
  mutate(attempter = as.factor(attempters)) %>% 
  # rename factor levels
  mutate(attempter = recode_factor(attempter, "yes" = "0", "no" = "1")) %>% 
  group_by(predictors, attempter) %>%
  summarize(severity = n(),.groups = "drop")
```

which got me a data frame as follows:

| predictors | attempters | severity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MDD | 0 | 1 |
| Anxiety | 1 | 1 |
| Anxiety | 0 | 2 |
| PTBS | 1 | 1 |
| PTBS | 0 | 1 |

and then used the following to plot:

```
plot_attempers <- data_attempters %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = attempter, y = severity,
             fill = attempter, group = attempter)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
    # position_dodge for avoid bar stacked on each other
    position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_fill_manual(labels = labs, values = c("0" = "#999999", "1" = "#CC79A7")) +
  facet_grid(.~ predictors) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 12), breaks = seq(0, 12, by = 1)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.x=element_blank()) +
  ylab("Frequency")
plot_attempers
```

Did I add something in the code where I converted the data which made me lose the data about those who do not have a certain diagnosis which is why it is not shown in my plot? Or what do I need to add to get the non-diagnosis-people in the plot as well? Because as I can see in the new data-frame, I did lose those who do not have a diagnosis ...
My plot looks like this so far (please ignore the diagnoses I did not mention in my explanation here. I did not include them in this post so it is a smaller sample as well):

[image: geom_bar]

I would want four bars per diagnosis (two per group, one of them representing people with the diagnosis and one representing the people without)

Answer (score 1):

You have to summarise your data first: Here I create a little example that simulate your data:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(code=1:100,
                 MDD=sample(0:1,100,replace = T,prob = c(0.3,0.7)),
                 anxiety=sample(0:1,100,replace = T,prob = c(0.4,0.6)),
                 PTBS=sample(0:1,100,replace = T),
                 attempters=sample(0:1,100,replace = T,prob = c(0.2,0.8)))

x <- reshape2::melt(df[,-1],id.vars="attempters",variable.name="diagnosis")

t <- x %>% group_by(diagnosis,attempters) %>%
     summarise(sick=sum(value==1),healt=sum(value==0))
t <- reshape2::melt(t,id.vars=c("diagnosis","attempters"))
tt <-as.data.frame( apply(t, 2, as.factor))

ggplot(tt,aes(x=attempters,y=value))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity",aes(fill=variable),position = "dodge")+
  facet_wrap(~diagnosis)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#CC79A7","#999999"))
```

and this is the resulting plot

[image]